# Realtime updated values?

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, push

How can I have a push mechanism within a JSF Java EE App?

I have several backend values, that may sometimes change every other second, sometime every other minute, sometimes only one time per hour.

I do not want to do pulling on that variable, as this will be expensive when several clients connect to that page.

So I somehow need a push mechanism to only update the values on frontend if they are changed. Does anyone know how I could do this?

Comment: I have never used it, but PrimeFaces provides Push support: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/index.jsf. You may also want to check its documentation: http://www.primefaces.org/documentation.html. Btw, have you checked the possibility of using Long Polling?

Comment: what exactly is long polling?

Comment: A little bit extensive to fully explain here. See this link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling. Basically, the request is made, but is only responded when there is something useful to return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Primefaces Push

> PrimePush, powered by the great [Atmosphere Framework](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere).

Here some ref's :

[PrimeFaces Push Unleashed](http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=2053)

[PrimePush](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/index.jsf)

[User's Guide 3.4](http://primefaces.googlecode.com/files/primefaces_users_guide_3_4.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

You can use RichFaces [a4j:push](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=push&sample=pushCdi&skin=blueSky). The client creates a permanent connection to the server either by using a WebSocket connection or the long-polling method. Permanent connections are managed by the [Atmosphere Framework](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere).
Push can be controlled by a programmatic API (Topic), or using CDI Events (@Push). Code is pretty lean.